# One check per column in one row for checkbox in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I was trying to figure out how to make so there would be one check per column in one row. So far, I was still looking for an way to do this via Apps Script extension which I have been met with disappointment.

So, for example, if you have two rows but needs to have one checks per columns in the respective row? How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### One Checkbox per column in one row

```
function oneCheckPerColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//change sheet name to fit your needs
  const rg = sh.getRange(1,1,1,10).insertCheckboxes();
}
```

#### Only one checked at a time

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.rowStart < 17 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.getRange("A2:A16").uncheck();
    e.range.check();
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

#### Rows and Columns

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.rowStart < 17 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.getRange("A2:A16").uncheck();
    e.range.check();
  }
  
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart < 12 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Flag2');
    sh.getRange("B2:K2").uncheck();
    e.range.check();
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I tried to use this code and it results in an error seen here: https://imgur.com/a/wM2tdKM

Comment: You probably did not change the sheet name to something that exists on your spreadsheet

Comment: Tested it and alli got was checkbox per column in one row. I was asking about how can you have one check per columns in one row of checkbox, not checkbox.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it behave as if it were a radio button group when only one can be checked at a time

Comment: Here's a radiogroup behavior

Comment: Good! But, I have one small problem when trying to run this code which results in this: https://imgur.com/a/eQ3RTKr any idea?

Comment: That is typical behavior when attempting to run onEdit triggered functions which utilize the event object because without the trigger supplying the event object many values are missing.  I recommend you save it in your project; Make the appropriate changes with regard to sheet name, range and other unique application specific items and test it in place.

Comment: What are the appropriate changes needed to make this work?

Comment: I'm sorry but if you are not willing to take the time to look at the code and figure that out for yourself then I believe that this forum is not for you.